# AWS Load Balancer Controller on EKS - Sticky Sessions Not Working

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes-ingress, amazon-eks, aws-application-load-balancer

I have deployed [AWS Load Balancer Controller on AWS EKS](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/eks-alb-ingress-controller-fargate/). I have created k8s Ingress resource
I am deploying java web application with k8s Deployment. I want to make sure sticky session holds to make my application work.

I have [read that](https://kubernetes-sigs.github.io/aws-load-balancer-controller/v2.2/guide/ingress/annotations/) if I set below annotation then sticky sessions will work :

```
alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/target-type: ip
```

But I am seeing ingress is routing requests to different replica each time letting login fail as session cookies are not persisting.

What am I missing here ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/target-type: ip` is required.

but the annotation to enable stickiness is:

`alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/target-group-attributes: stickiness.enabled=true`

Also you can set `cookie_duration_settings`.

```
alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/target-group-attributes: stickiness.enabled=true,stickiness.lb_cookie.duration_seconds=300
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to manage the stick session from the K8s level you can use the, `sessionAffinity: ClientIP`

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: service
spec:
  selector:
    app: app
  ports:
  - name: http
    protocol: TCP
    port: 80
    targetPort: 80
  sessionAffinity: ClientIP
  sessionAffinityConfig:
    clientIP:
      timeoutSeconds: 10000
```